# MongoDB search via index of documents containing JSON

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have objects in a MongoDB collection:

```
{
    ...
    "json" : "{\"things\":[2494090781803658355,5114030115038563045,3035856943768375362,8931213615561493991,7574631742057150605,480863244020297489]}"
}
```

It's an Azure "MongoDB" so doesn't support all the features, but suppose it does.

This search will find that document:

```
db.coll.find({"json" : {$regex : "5114030115038563045|8931213615561493991"}})
```

Of course, it's scanning the whole collection to pull these records out. What's an efficient/faster way to find documents where the list of "things"
contains any of a list of "things" in a query? It seems like throwing a search engine like Solr or ElasticSearch would solve this, and perhaps
using another Azure's Data Lake storage would make this more searchable, so I'm considering those options. They're outside the scope of this
question though; I'd like to know if there's a Mongo-ish way to search this collection by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option you have available to you if you're storing a JSON string is to use a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) with a [$text operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/).

If this document structure isn't set in stone, however, you might consider also separately storing the JSON as a nested subdocument (with the appropriate sanitation, of course). This would allow you to construct an index on `json.things`, while still storing the JSON string, and allow you to perform a query on e.g. `"json.things": {$in: [ "5114030115038563045", "8931213615561493991" ]}`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: A quick test over 5000 documents showed a 70x improvement. I guess that justifies an "accept." ;)

Comment: That's using the nested document approach, btw.